# Call static method from string in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to call this from string `Yii::app()->user->id_rol`. So, I want to take this string and do the call then.

I tried to do this:

```
$class = "Yii::app()->user->id_rol";
$class = explode('::',$class);
$class[1] = explode('->',$class[1]); 

$class2 = new $class[0];
$string = "";
$n = count($class[1]);
for($i = 0; $i<$n;$i++){
(($i+1) == $n) ? $fl = '' : $fl = '->';
$string .= $class[1][$i].$fl;
}

$model = $class2->$string;
```

...but that doesn't work.

> Undefined property: Yii::$app()->user->id_rol

How could I make it work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, bigger picture, here?

Comment: i'm trying to specify the var name to recieve rol id in my new module in params, like this    'evaluation' => array(
  'id_rol'=>'Yii::app()->user->id_rol',
  ),
So, i need to take this literal string as the variable

Comment: What about `$prop = 'id_rol'; Yii::app()->user->$prop`?

Comment: that could work, but, if someone write for example..."Yii::app()->params['user']['id_rol']" I going to have an error. I need to take the exactly string and used it

Comment: You last 4 lines could be simplified to $string = implode($class[1], '->');

Answer (score 0):

I think mnv's comment above is the way to go.  Otherwise you risk all sorts of problems with code injection and whatnot.  In the worst case, if you really want to do this, I'd recommend doing the following (as much as it pains me to write this):

```
$code = "return {$VARIABLE_FROM_DB};";
$value = eval($code);
```

That said, there should be a better way to do what you are trying to do overall.  What is the source of the DB provided code?  Can you reformat it in a way that you are not saving code into the database?